# What does "email exchange" mean?

Tags: meaning, nouns, email

What does "email exchange" mean?

Answer (score 5):

An "email exchange" or "exchange of emails" is a series of emails between two or more participants, each generally a response to the previous email.  With multiple participants you can get a tree of parallel responses rather than a simple linear chain, but the principle is the same.

Comment: Spot on response!